# Please help to achieve the following requirement in html or jquery

Tags: html, jquery

If user clicks button1, then new tab opens. If user then clicks button2 then that same new tab should be refreshed.

Eg: On existing page I have LLP button and Event button. on click of LLP new tab should open with one link and on click of Event the same tab should refresh to display other link. Both tabs should be named same.

I tried this, on button click it opens new tab and if I click the same button again then page refreshes without opening new tab. But with this 2 tabs will open. what I need is on click of both buttons same newtab should get refreshed with different urls.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, Stack Overflow is not a coding service. When you have tried, include the attempt in your question and then we will be happy to assist you.

Comment: <a href="otherpage.html" target="other-page">Click here</a>

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your question.

Comment: They both have to have the same `target=` and it needs to be something other than one of the "special" ones, eg `target="mypage"` *on both*.

Comment: yeah, Its working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the target attribute has specific values for different purposes.
refer to this page for more information
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_parent"/>
```

this opens google.com in same tab

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"/>
```

this opens google.com in new tab